# Unable to update table, but select works

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I`m facing a weird problem in MySQL, I try to update a value in a table that exists, but get an error that the table doesn't exists even though it does. The SELECT statement works fine:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM CurrentState;
+----+------------+--------+--------+
| ID | last_price | buyer  | seller |
+----+------------+--------+--------+
|  1 |       5.10 |   5.09 |   5.12 |
|  2 |     132.00 | 130.30 | 132.40 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE CurrentState SET buyer = buyer;
ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'CurrentState' in field list
```

I have tried doing the query as a regular user and as root and I get the same results. What can the problem be? The only thing I have done is that I have created a trigger for the table in case an update statement is executed. But now that isn't even possible.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Added trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER push_changes AFTER UPDATE ON CurrentState FOR EACH ROW CALL winners_change(CurrentState.buyer,CurrentState.seller,CurrentState.last_price);
```

As I write this I guess the problem is the `(CurrentState.buyer,CurrentState.seller,CurrentState.last_price);` part, should `CurrentState` be removed?

Comment: we need to see the trigger you added, it probably is the problem.

Comment: @redmoon7777: Thanks for your reply, trigger has been added.

Comment: @redmoon7777: Thanks, that seemed to solve the problem :) Apply your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NEW` instead of `CurrentState` to reference the current row.

Answer (score 1):

```
CALL winners_change(CurrentState.buyer,CurrentState.seller,CurrentState.last_price);
```

should be

```
CALL winners_change(NEW.buyer,NEW.seller,NEW.last_price);
```